# How to validate using rule `present` when another node is of a particular value in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

so I have this issue I am faced with since a while now.

i have a validation rule that is like this

```
'editors' => ['required_if:type,journal', 'array', 'min:1'],
```

but I want to change the validation to accept an empty array but I want that field to be present if type=journal.. but I seem not to know how to go about it.. I will appreciate any assistance. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's something complex you could always do  a custom rule like this:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

So, in your rules:

```php
 return [
     'editors' => [
         new CustomRule()
   ],
];
```

To create a custom rule go to the command line and do:

php artisan make:rule CustomRule

and after you can put any logic to it.